# Replace null value by latest value

Tags: sql-server-2008, replace, null

Say I have below table. How do I pick up the latest previous value in case my joined table to not match the date and currency? On the null DKK value I want it to pick up 3. Note that dates do not exist every day since I do not load the tables on weekends.

```
Select
    PositionDate,
    Currency,
    T2.Value,
    isnull(t2.value, ? )
From t1
left join t2
on t1.currency = t2.Currency
and t1.PositionDate = t2.PositionDate
```

.

```
PositionDate    Currency        Value
2017-04-11      SEK               1
2017-04-11      DKK               NULL
2017-04-11      EUR               7
2017-04-10      SEK               4 
2017-04-10      DKK               3
2017-04-10      EUR               5
2017-04-07      SEK               4 
2017-04-07      DKK               3
2017-04-07      EUR               5
```

.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for your case i think:

```
SELECT 
    t1.PositionDate,
    t1.Currency,
    COALESCE(t1.Value,t2.value) AS Value
FROM t1
LEFT join (SELECT MAX(PositionDate) AS PositionDate,Currency FROM t2 WHERE PositionDate < t1.PositionDate  GROUP BY Currency) tjoin
LEFT join t2 on tjoin.currency = t2.Currency and tjoin.PositionDate = t2.PositionDate
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Achieve it by using CTE and Case condition.

```
With cte as
(
    Select
        PositionDate,
        Currency,
        T2.Value,
    From t1
    left join t2
    on t1.currency = t2.Currency
    and t1.PositionDate = t2.PositionDate
        and t1.PositionDate = t2.PositionDate
)
select PositionDate, Currency, Value, 
   CASE WHEN ISNULL(value,'')='' THEN
    (Select top 1 from cte cin where cin.currency=cout.currency order by CONVERT(Date,PositionDate) desc)
   ELSE
    Value 
   END as Value2 
   From cte cout
```